# Iterate over all files in folder with bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a bunch of markdown files in my folder which I would like to convert to html with pandoc.

The command I typically use is

```
pandoc Atten.md -f markdown -t html --css pandoc.css -o Atten.html
```

where `Atten.md` is the name of a typical markdown file. However, I would like to iterate over all files and convert .md to .html as done above. How do I do that in bash or zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find`:

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c '
      pandoc -f markdown -t html --css pandoc.css -o "${1%.*}.html" "$1"
   ' find-sh {} \;
```

It should work in Bash, Zsh and many other shells. The only job of the outer shell is to run `find` with proper arguments.

This version spawns a single `sh` to process as many files as it can (more `sh` processes will be spawned if needed):

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c '
      for f; do
         pandoc -f markdown -t html --css pandoc.css -o "${f%.*}.html" "$f"
      done
   ' find-sh {} +
```

Notes:

- The inner shell is invoked only because we need to remove the old extension. If it was not the requirement, then a solution with `… -exec pandoc … -o {}.html {} \;` would probably work. "Probably" because POSIX requires `find` to replace one sole `{}`. It's a "courtesy" of the `find` implementation you use, if anything more is replaced (like `{}.html` or the second appearance of `{}`).
- `-execdir` instead of `-exec` would be better but it's not POSIX.
- `-execdir` would allow us to use `./"$1"` instead of `"$1"` (respectively: `./"$f"` instead of `"$f"`) to prevent it being interpreted by `pandoc` as an option. Another approach is [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618) but I don't know if `pandoc` supports it. I think in your case `"$1"` cannot expand to anything starting with `-` because it must start with `path/to/dir`, and if `path/to/dir` started with `-` then it would be misinterpreted by `find` in the first place. In general though this concern is legitimate.
- In `pandoc` invocation I moved the operand to the end only because of my fondness towards the most common order of `command -options operands`.
- The solution is recursive. To make it non-recursive specify `-maxdepth 1`. If your `find` doesn't support `-maxdepth` then study [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618) or drop `find` and let the outer shell iterate over files:

  ```
  # written for Bash
  ( cd path/to/dir || exit 125
  for f in ./*.md ./.*.md; do
      [ -f "$f" ] &&
      pandoc -f markdown -t html --css pandoc.css -o "${f%.*}.html" "$f"
  done )
  ```

  Notes specific to the above code:

  - The subshell is for `cd` to work without affecting the current shell.
  - If `cd` fails for whatever reason then the rest will not be executed. This is a good practice.
  - `./*.md` instead of plain `*.md` prevents `"$f"` from being interpreted as an option later.
  - `./.*.md` is added because `./*.md` does not match dotfiles.
  - `[ -f "$f" ]` is to prevent

    - invoking `pandoc` for directories, special files and such;
    - invoking `pandoc` for nonexistent `./*.md` (or `./.*.md`) when nothing matches the pattern.
  - Zsh is somewhat different. The code should work in `sh` though and because a subshell is useful anyway then it wouldn't make much difference if you called `sh` explicitly from any sane shell:

    ```
    sh -c 'cd path/to/dir || exit 125
           for …
           done '
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find` and its `-exec` (see [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)):

```
find YourDirectory -name \*.md | \
  while IFS= read fn; do \
  pandoc ${fn} -f markdown -t html --css pandoc.css -o ${fn%.md}.html ; done
```

Or maybe `-execdir`.

Comment: Is this for bash or zsh? See [my comment under the other answer](https://superuser.com/q/1487597/432690#comment2244547_1487618). Another thing: investigate `read` vs `IFS= read -r`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it should work on `bash`.

Comment: For some file names it will not work.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Do not pipe `find` output to a `read` statement like that. Use `find … -print0` and `read -r -d`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for more info.

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate the file with a for:

```bsh
for item in *.md; do CONVERT_FILE_COMMAND $item "$(basename '$item' .md).html; done
```

Comment: I revoked my downvote although your code is still flawed. The OP specified "bash or zsh". In zsh you don't have to quote variables, but in bash you do [or else bad things will happen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618). Either write universal code or specify the shell. In addition there is unpaired `"`.